In MS Access VBA how can I get it to tell me (e.g., variable) where the data is coming from?
I want to have a procedure tell me the tablename/field data source of the current control.
I can find lots of explanations on how to set a value, but I want the control property 'control source'.
I'm trying to create a generic popup that will display the full contents of the current (memo) field in a scrollable, editable format.  For that I need to know the identity of the information, either so that I can pull it from the form, or from the table. surely I don't assign the entire contents of the memo field as a string?
I need the OPPOSITE of this  Forms!Customers!AddressPart.ControlSource = "City"
I need to know the tablename/fieldname which is in the Design view properties list as "Control Source"
Why can't I just ask vba where the control's data comes from?
All the documentation that I can find is about setting the value, not getting the value.  I have searched the MS sites and asked google in every different way that I can think of.  I literally can't find a simple table listing all the control properties and find the (source) values.

"surely I don't assign the entire contents of the memo field as a string?" - actually, yes, that's how you do it. While Access Forms/Reports can be bound directly to a column-expression the result is an rigid and unusable UX. (More-or-less the same reason all those 4GL systems all died-off in the early-2000s)

If you want what is in the ControlSource property: sSrc = Forms!Customers.AddressPart.ControlSource. If you want what is in the Value property: sVal = Forms!Customers.AddressPart (Value is default property of data controls so does not have to be referenced). I always name controls different from the field name so I would use tbxAddress as a textbox name.

thanks for the assist.  I can use the sScr example and get a message box to display the contents of the field, unformatted.  I can't get the Val to work.  Does it need to be Dim s something other than a string?  I've tried to look up AddressPart (although I've seen the term before) and I can't get anything to come up in Google.  It doesn't come up as an option when I am typing the code.

Every form and table has two memo fields.  Surely a form and module could be used to display, edit and write back to original control?

Use OpenArgs of the popup form.
In your form (Customers) to open the popup form to edit the memo:
Dim MyMemo As Variant

MyMemo = Me!AddressPart.Value
DoCmd.OpenForm "NameOfYourPopupForm", , , , , , MyMemo

In the Load event of your popup form:
Me!YourMemoEditTextBoxName.Value = Me.OpenArgs

In the Unload event of the popup form:
Forms!Customers!AddressPart.Value = Me!YourMemoEditTextBoxName.Value

